# MisconfigurationException: You requested GPUs: [0] But your machine only has: []

Tags: pytorch, gpu, jupyter, tensor, amazon-sagemaker

I'm running `JupyterLab` via. `AWS SageMaker`.

I've been taking AWS certifications, but this is my first time actively using `AWS`.

---

Update:

I have changed the Notebook instance type to `ml.g4dn.xlarge`, a GPU.

Will run and see what happens.

**How do I change the instance types of `EC2` to `GPU`?**

---

In `Google Colab`, e.g., you can select which hardware accelerator to use, one of which being `GPU`.

Error:

```
MisconfigurationException: You requested GPUs: [0]
 But your machine only has: []
```

---

SageMaker environment:
[image]

List of Kernels:
I'm on `conda_python3`.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to determine if you are you using a [SageMaker Studio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio.html) or [SageMaker notebook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi.html) instance.

Since you are using SageMaker notebooks, you first need to go back to SageMaker console, select the correct notebook, and stop it.

[image]

Once the notebooks is stopped, you can edit the configuration and select an instance that has GPU. You can find the list of all instances [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-instance-types.html).

[image]

---

In Sagemaker studio, you can select a `PyTorch GPU optimized` **kernel**

[image]

and then select an **instance** that has GPU.

[image]

Comment: Will try this all now and get back to you. Ty @AmirImani

Comment: On AWS Console, top navigation states: `Amazon SageMaker` > `Notebook instances`. Also, `URL` contains "notebook": `https://<project_name>.notebook.eu-central-1.sagemaker.aws/lab`.

Comment: I've attached a screenshot, to my post, of my `SageMaker` enviroment and list of `kernels`.

Comment: so you are using SageMaker notebook instances. unlike studio, you can't change the underlying instance in runtime. you need to stop the instance and change the instance type to one with GPU and restart it. I will update my answer as well

Comment: Yes, I learnt this. I selected GPU instance types with `ResourceLimitExceeded` errors. So, I have made a service requested to AWS. I'll keep posted. Thanks @AmirImani